# how to abort a service call if taking more time while call service through script tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling a service through Script tag src as follows:

making js script tag on run time and service response has a call back function. so i just need to set a time out while service will not respond let say after 10 second.

code is as follows:

```
function abc(URL){
var NewScript = d.createElement("script");
            NewScript.type = "text/javascript";
            NewScript.src = url + '&_' + Math.random();
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(NewScript);
}


abc('www.example.com?callback=testcallback');
```

Here i want to abort service call if service taking too much time (lets say 30 seconds). Please note i am calling service as an ajax from dynamically  added script tag with service URL as script src.

Thanks,

Comment: @dev_feed  In that post its only adding setInterval which is not relevance to my question. if am it getting wrong, can you please alter my code and provide me...it would be great help...

Comment: @dev_feed how can u say this question is duplicate I  check  to this and those but it's not duplicate it's totally different .

Comment: Do you need to call the service by adding in a `<script>` element?  This is potentially an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where instead of trying to cancel this request you should instead be making a totally different one, eg using XMLHttpRequest, where you have much better control over the request.

Comment: @James Thorpe, yeah!! you are right by XMLHttpRequest i can solve this but i have some limitation like i am getting cross domain issue with it. so i am calling through <script> that is working fine except set timeout issue...

Comment: @YPS you're right, thanks. removed flag.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var returned = false;

function checkTimeout(script) {
    returned = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (returned == false) {
            // Script NOT loaded
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
        } else {
            // Script loaded
        }
    }, 10000);
}

function abs(URL) {
    var NewScript = d.createElement("script");
    NewScript.type = "text/javascript";
    NewScript.src = url + '&_' + Math.random();
    checkTimeout(NewScript);
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(NewScript);
}

abs('someurl');
```

And then in the script you are loading:

```
returned = true;

// Rest of other script
```

Now please note, this is just a general concept, I haven't actually tried this out. Also, it might pay to encapsulate all of this into an "object" to make it easier.

Comment: Not able to solve my problem with this.........can you please let me know how it call abort the service call  while we are call timeout function before adding service url set..